# закруглить (сгладить) углы в Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Подскажите пожалуйста, как закруглить (сгладить) углы у элемента (например TextView) в Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

Вам придется использовать собственные рендер в проектах для таких элементов.

к примеру часть синтаксиса для Android

```
   android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
   android:topRightRadius="15dp"
```

и переписывать логику для View.

Возможно имеет смысл писать проект Xamarin.Native так как там все View пишутся под платформу.